# Constant issues with Tableau custom sql and Athena

Tags: tableau-api, amazon-athena, presto

Queries I seem to be easily able to run in SQL workbench just don't work in Tableau - it's literally one java error after another... rant over.

One thing I've noticed is that Tableau keeps trying to wrap an additional SELECT which Athena doesn't recognise. I thought I could overcome this using Athena views, but that doens't seem to work either.

When I do the following in Tableau:

```
SELECT count(distinct uuid), category
FROM "pregnancy_analytics"."final_test_parquet"
GROUP BY category
```

I get the following in Athena (that throws an error - SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: Column 'tableausql._col0' cannot be resolved). As I say, since it looks like Tableau is trying to "nest" the SELECT:

```
SELECT "TableauSQL"."_col0" AS "xcol0"
FROM (
  SELECT count(distinct uuid)
  FROM "pregnancy_analytics"."final_test_parquet"
  WHERE category = ''
  LIMIT 100
) "TableauSQL"
LIMIT 10000
```

NB: The error, as I said above, arises because Tableau sticks another SELECT around this to a table that doesn't exist, and as such Athena kicks up an error.

Starting to feel like Tableau is not a good fit with Athena? Is there a better suggestion perhaps?

Thanks!

Comment: In general, Tableau works great with Presto and so it should work with Athena as well. "... because Tableau sticks another SELECT around this to a table" -- it could be helpful if you included the query that is being sent to the database.

Comment: Added the example above :)

Comment: In my case with Cloudera Hadool JDBC connection  Table alias-> ` TableauSQL `  that tableau wraps to customsql gives the problem  (The Backticks are causing the issue, ignore spaces) , but I could not find a way to disable it.  Also Tableau generates nonsense column names that do not exists 
 like>   SELECT `TableauSQL`.`tableausql.my_original_column_name` AS